# Setup RouterLink

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

I need a url like http://localhost:8000/user/firstName-lastName

So I didn't get any idea that how can we do this with routerlink

Can anyone help me with this one?
Thank You in Advance

### This is not working

[routerLink] = "['/user',user.firstName-user.lastName]"

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: It is going like this `http://localhost:8000/user/NaN`

Comment: You need to connect the variables as strings, not as numbers: `user.firstName + '-' + user.lastName`, or: `${user.firstName}-${user.lastName}`

Comment: Read the docs https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description

Answer (score 1):

You should do this instead

```
[routerLink] = "['/user',user.firstName + '-' + user.lastName]"
```

Make the  `-` a string so it just concatenates your two variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try too

> [routerLink] = [`/user${user.firstName}-${user.lastName}`]

It works too

`[routerLink] = "['/user',user.firstName + '-' + user.lastName]"`